# How to install seprate OSs on different partitions

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning

I know its a newbie question but I have a VAIO VGN-CR353 running linux openSuSE 12.2. The Hard-disk has only one partition (under IDE there is only home/sda1). I want to install Windows on a separate partition without affecting the current OS, can I do that? And if not, I am willing to remove and reinstall the current installation of linux, but I'm not sure how to separate partitions and ensure each OS runs on a single partition. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if **gparted** is available on SuSE, but if so it makes resizing partitions very easy and straightforward. If not run it from an Ubuntu Live CD. Simply move one of the boundaries up or down to make space for the Windows partition, which you then create in the free space. You may need to use a Live CD to re-install **grub** afterwards: I've not tried installing Windows on to a Linux system, so I don't know what the Windows install will do to the boot sequence.

Answer (score 1):

AFH has the right answer although I would say that installing Windows first and then installing Linux to another partition is easier then the other way around.

One alternative is to use a virtual machine (like Virtual Box) running in Linux to install Windows to. Then you don't have to worry about partitioning.

Answer (score 1):

If OpenSuse doesn't have `gparted` in it you can [download](http://www.susegeek.com/utility/gparted-gnome-partition-editor-in-opensuse/) it from [Gparted](http://software.opensuse.org/package/gparted) site. Also you can boot up your machine from [Gparted Live CD](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted-live-stable/0.19.0-1/gparted-live-0.19.0-1-i486.iso/download?use_mirror=aarnet)

How two operate in `Gparted` you can find in these to threads below:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/51272/how-do-i-repartition-with-gparted

https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions

Also after installing Windows you will need to [repair boot](http://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Repair_MBR_after_Windows_install).

Most likely you would find it easier to install Windows first and then Linux. Linux always finds Windows and keeps it working just adding dual boot in menu.